# How can I stop the loop using break?

Tags: c++

I'm still new on C++ program and I can't seem to understand the use of break statement yet.Is my coding down here correct to break the loop?

```
int validateHours(int nohours)
{

    while (nohours < 0 || nohours > 150)
    {
        cout << "Error! Hours cannot be negative or exceed 150" << endl;
        cin >> nohours;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you need a `break` here. That's what the condition is for.

Comment: When a [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) is encountered, it stops the loop. If a `break` is *always* encountered, the loop will *always* stop on the first iteration.

Comment: Get a good C++ book and read it. You'll save a ton of time.

Comment: @Zahir To immediately return to the main function, rather use a `return`statement under some appropriate condition.

Comment: This can't work because you are checking `nohours` before you have read it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already added conditions at the start of `while` loop, there is no need of `break` here.

You can use `break` like this.

```
int validateHours(int nohours)
{
    while (true) // Removed condition and loop is foreever ture
    {
        cout << "Error! Hours cannot be negative or exceed 150" << endl;
        cin >> nohours;
        if(nohours < 0 || nohours > 150) {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think author intended to write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int validateHours(int nohours);

int main(int arc, char* argv) {
    int nohours;
    while (true) {
       cin >> nohours;
       if (validateHours(nohours) == 0) {
           break;
       }
    }
}

int validateHours(int nohours)
{
    if(nohours < 0 || nohours > 150) {
        cout << "Error! Hours cannot be negative or exceed 150" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```